# Can Erlang Nodes be able to communicate though they are not sharing the same cookie?

Tags: security, erlang

Can two Erlang nodes communicate using the Erlang standard distribution protocol even if they do not share the same cookie ?

P.S: from erlang certification exam and already referred to this link [Erlang : Disallowed Nodes / Maybe Cookie question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/451583/erlang-disallowed-nodes-maybe-cookie-question)
but did not able to get a clear idea.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Two nodes must share the same cookie to be able to communicate with each other.

Comment: This is not strictly true.  There is the possibility to install your own handler of bad cookie, which could then do whatever magic is deemed wanted when the cookies don't match.  Same thing as installing your own error_handler for loading modules which don't exist.  (Can't find how to do this right now though, so I'm wondering if this has changed in recent Erlang versions)  Anyway.  Don't go there.

Comment: It's `error_handler:undefined_function/3` which is called when you make a call to a function in another module which doesn't exist. It is there you can check if the module is loaded, in which case the function doesn't exist and signal an error, or decide whether to load it and try again.

Comment: I know about `error_handler:undefined_function/3`.  It's the cookie handler that I cannot find how to personalize.